# Selective Copy - Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I am having an issue with the os.walk() function within my code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# selectiveCopy.py - walks through a folder and copies all pdf files
# and puts them in a new pdf only folder

import os, shutil

def selectiveCopy(folder, destination):

    #walks through folder using os.walk(folder)
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        print('in os.walk() for ' + folder)
        for filename in filenames:
            # select files with pdf ending
            if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                print('Copying %s from %s to %s...' % (
                    filename, foldername, destination))
                #shutil.copy(os.path.join(foldername,filename), destination')
    #adds files with folder.endswith('.pdf') to new folder

selectiveCopy('./folder1',
              './folder1/pdf_Folder')
```

When I run the code, it never makes it to the first print statement showing me that it is actually in the os.walk function. I could not figure out what the issue was. Any help is appreciated. The actual folder and destination that I use are the absolute path not the relative path like I have in the example below

Answer (score 0):

So, all I did was add a '/' to the end of both the folder and destination file path and now it works perfectly. If anyone has this problem, try that first. Not sure why it works based off only that, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because of less than 50 reputation (as of now).

Yes, you have to add a / before the file paths because that's how file paths work in macOS. If you've noticed, your root dir is like this: `/Users/...`. Not this: `Users/...`